# SQL Server Isolation Levels

Tags: sql-server, isolation

This question may have been asked but from what I've read I still don't clearly understand what's happening. My question deals specifically with using the Read Uncommitted isolation level in SQL Server - via Entity Framework (i.e. setting the isolation level on the DB object in the contest when starting a transaction).

My question is - the documentation states that using read uncommitted will allow other transactions/queries to read the tables involved in the initial transaction. Now this works fine up until a write based operation is performed. At that point the table is locked. I've tested this out by starting a transaction in a project and stopping in a breakpoint after the update. Then tried to access the related table in SQL Server Management Studio. I am not able to do so. This makes me wonder what the purpose of read uncommitted is if you can't read uncommitted. I have read that people state that there are two types of locking behaviour and the second one which is not affected by the isolation level is what is locking the table. This still doesn't explain why the read uncommitted is not working - again it states that it allows reading of uncommitted operations (but seems to not allow it).

Peter

Comment: During a "write" operation (insert, update, delete), the table is **NOT** locked by default. SQL Server uses **row-level** locks by default, and only occasionally "escalates" those locks to a table-level lock

Comment: Unless you REALLY understand what you are doing you should avoid the read uncommitted isolation like the plague. And once you do fully understand it, you will avoid it like the plague except in very rare cases. Using that isolation level is the same thing as putting NOLOCK on every single query. Here is a great article discussing the foibles of that approach. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Thanks for the input. My question really deals with trying to understand why there is an isolation level named read uncommitted - but run into situations where reading uncommitted records is not being allowed. I understand all the pitfalls related to this and transaction level processing; just trying to get my head around a feature that does not seem to work. The testing I'm doing has a transaction making operations on multiple tables - adding/updating/deleting. Would this be why the locking escalates to the table level?